# javascript: how to clean the following innertext in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having the following text  "sometext  ⚽️ ".

I want to get only sometext and remove the ball and .

HOw to do that in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace non-ascii characters using regular expressions:

```js
var s = "sometext ⚽️ ";
var s2 = s.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, '')

console.log(s2);
```

Comment: It would be clearer if put as `[^\u0000-\u007F]` since regex and String operate on/are UTF-16 code units. Conceptually getting from \x7F to \u007F requires intimate knowledge of JavaScript, ISO-8859-1, and Unicode, whereas only essential basic knowledge of JavaScript, Unicode and UTF-16 should be required.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last two characters.

```
str = yourDiv.innerHTML;
str = str.substr(0,str.length-2);
yourDiv.innerHTML = str;
```